# Pycharm cannot find profiler

Tags: python, pycharm, profiling

I am using Pycharm 2017.2

When I try to run the profiler, it raises an error stating:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/172.3317.103/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/profiler/run_profiler.py'

I tried searching for this error online but I can't find anything. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207719925-PyCharm-Profiler-is-not-working

> When you run profiler, the PyCharm runs the `pydevd` module which is part of your PyCharm installation. But you have a `pydevd` package installed on your Python interpreter, and Python runs it instead of `pydevd` module from PyCharm.
>
> We share `pydevd` package with PyDev, and there are some problems with synchronizing the `pydevd` module between us. So, please, uninstall the `pydevd` package from your interpreter or use another interpreter.

Comment: thank you, but I had seen that blogpost and it does not help me. We have different error messages, and I never installed the pydevd module. I use conda, but calling "conda list" does not show the pydevd module, and "import pydevd" raises an error. So I don't think this is the problem :/